# How to use Regex look behind?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following URL: www.exampe.com/id/1234 and I want a regex that gets the value of the id parameter which in this case is `1234`.

I tried

```
<?php
$url = "www.exampe.com/id/1234";
preg_match("/\d+(?<=id\/[\d])/",$url,$matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

and got `Array ( [0] => 1 )` which is displaying the first digit only.

The question is, how do I rewrite the regex to get all the digits using positive look behind?

Comment: why do you want a look behind?

Comment: I was trying to solve a more complicated problem and am using this example to make it simple.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not just `preg_match('(id/(\d+))', $url, $matches)` without any lookbehind? The result will be in `$matches[1]`.

By the way, the correct lookbehind expression would be `((?<=id/)\d+)`, but you really shouldn't use lookbehind unless you need it.

Another alternative is `(id/\K\d+)` (`\K` resets the match start and is often used as a more powerful lookbehind).

Comment: Thanks much. My main concern was to figure out why the look behind was not working. Am not familiar with the `\K` but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with NikiC that you don't need to use lookbehind; but since you ask — you can write

```
<?php
$url = "www.exampe.com/id/1234";
preg_match("/(?<=id\/)\d+/",$url,$matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```